# Tornado Execution Order Spawn callback

Tags: tornado

If I have something like the following:

```
 @tornado.gen.coroutine
 def first(x):
    # 
    # do stuff


    for i in I:
       tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(func,i)

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(func2,z)

 yield first(xxx)
```

Can I be guaranteed that all the spawned functions in the `for` loop will run before the last spawning of callback to func2()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, in fact you're guaranteed that all the functions are spawned before any of them starts running, because `first` does not `yield` between spawning `func` and spawning `func2`. You can verify this yourself by testing your code:

```
from tornado import gen, ioloop

@gen.coroutine
def func():
    print('func started')
    yield gen.moment
    print('func done')


@gen.coroutine
def func2():
    print('func2 started')
    yield gen.moment
    print('func2 done')


@gen.coroutine
def first():
    for i in range(2):
        ioloop.IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(func)

    ioloop.IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(func2)
    yield gen.sleep(1)

ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(first)
```

It prints:

```
func started
func started
func2 started
func done
func done
func2 done
```

See, `func2` begins before the coroutines running `func` complete.

To accomplish what you want:

```
@gen.coroutine
def first():
    yield [func() for i in range(2)]
    ioloop.IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(func2)
```

This prints:

```
func started
func started
func done
func done
func2 started
func2 done
```

If you want `first` to wait for `func2` to finish before it exits, then:

```
@gen.coroutine
def first():
    yield [func() for i in range(2)]
    yield func2()
```

For more info on calling coroutines from coroutines, see my [Refactoring Tornado Coroutines](https://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that Jesse much appreciated.